# Laravel echo not responding whatsoever

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I have a bootstrap modal. When the modal is open, I want to add the user to a "queue". When the modal is closed, I want to remove them from said queue. They should also be removed from the queue if they leave the page etc.

Here is what I've done.

Configured `.env`:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID=(i put my app id here)
PUSHER_APP_KEY=(i put my app key here)
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=(i put my app secret here)
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=us2
```

I uncommented `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,` in `config.app`.

Added the channel to `routes/channel`:

```
Broadcast::channel('queue', function (\App\User $user) {
    return $user->toArray();
});
```

Created my event classes:

```
class QueueJoined implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('queue');
    }
}

class QueueLeft implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('queue');
    }
}
```

Added my scripts (I'm using laravel livewire):

```
<script>
    window.livewire.on('show-modal', () => {
        $('#queue-modal').modal('show');
        console.log('show-modal'); // called

        Echo.join('queue')
            .joining((user) => {
                window.livewire.call('joining-queue');
                console.log('joining: ' + user.name); // not called
            })
            .leaving((user) => {
                window.livewire.call('leaving-queue');
                console.log('leaving: ' + user.name); // not called
            })
            .listen('QueueJoined', (e) => {
                console.log('QueueJoined: ' + e.user.name); // not called
            })
            .listen('QueueLeft', (e) => {
                console.log('QueueLeft: ' + e.user.name); // not called
            });
    });
    window.livewire.on('hide-modal', () => {
        $('#queue-modal').modal('hide');
        console.log('hide-modal'); // called

        Echo.leave('queue');
    });
</script>
```

I've commented where the calls get made so far.

This is my livewire component class:

```
class Queue extends Component
{
    public $message;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.queue');
    }

    public function showModal()
    {
        $this->message = 'Joining queue...';
        $this->emit('show-modal');
    }

    public function hideModal()
    {
        $this->message = 'Leaving queue...';
        $this->emit('hide-modal');
    }

    public function joiningQueue()
    {
        $this->message = 'Queue joined! Finding match...';
        // add to queue table
        broadcast(new QueueJoined(Auth::user()));
    }

    public function leavingQueue()
    {
        $this->message = 'Queue left.';
        // remove from queue table
        broadcast(new QueueLeft(Auth::user()));
    }
}
```

I also am running `php artisan queue:listen` right now.

Nothing is working in regards to the broadcast. Pusher even shows 0 connections. I am also not getting any errors in the Laravel error log or the Chrome console.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you instantiated your Echo object? See 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo

```window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-channels-key'
});```

Comment: Yes I have instantiated it.

Comment: Are other users joining and leaving the channel correctly? The events you have subscribed to will be triggered only when another user joins or leaves the channel.
You could try binding to the `here` event to check the users that are present upon subscription. 
Finally, do you see any activity in the Pusher debug console?